# cordova admob with meteor 1.4 not working

Tags: cordova, meteor, admob, cordova-admob

I have an application under meteor 1.4 and im trying to add interstitials add from admob platform. I tried with this plugin which seemed documented for meteor : https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/wiki/06.-How-To-Use-with-Meteor so i used this plugin :

```
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-admobpro@2.20.1
```

i added this in my mobile-config.js :

```
App.accessRule("*");
```

i added this in my home.js (client side) :

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  if (Meteor.isCordova) {
    if (AdMob) {
      AdMob.prepareInterstitial( {
        adId: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxxx',
        autoShow: false,
        success: function() {
          console.log("Received ad");
        },
        error: function() {
          console.log("No ad received");
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log("No Admob");
    }

  } else {
    console.log("No Cordova ");
  }
});
```

but now when i try to use AdMob.showInterstitial() in the console i get an "undefined" response...

is there something im missing ? anyone had more luck using admob with meteor i would really appreciate a help i'm stuck there since hours...

thanks

Comment: Hi I did the same but I get AdMob is not defined.  Did you have to import AdMob at the top of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with other plugins, the installation should be similar. I would try with https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova

```
meteor add cordova:cordova-admob@4.1.10
```

Interstitials is very well documented and there is a full example at https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/showInterstitialAd